# Macbook preview shows the right pdf file, Adobe repeats 1 page 3 times

Tags: pdf, preview

I have to append one pdf file by 2 single pages. I do this in preview and the complete pdf file now has 4 pages and displays correctly in Preview, pages one through 4.

If I open the same 4 page pdf file in Acrobat Reader 10, the first 2 pages are the same but the rest are just repeats of old p. 2.

From the same pdf file at the same location two outputs, how is that possible?

Comment: That is odd. What happens if you print your modified PDF from within Preview.app to a PDF? Does Acrobat then do the same thing? I know it doesn't *solve* the issue, but it might be a workaround till the solution to the problem is discovered.

Comment: @SteveChambers Printing a PDF to PDF is actually a 'destructive' process, which will remove metadata and things like Table of Contents, Annotations, etc.

Comment: What OS version is this? Have you closed the document in Preview before opening in Acrobat? Can you share the PDF for us to look at?

Comment: The OS is 12.1, Monterey. Odd things happened today: I created 3 sets of files with equal data on p.1, and separte data on p. 2So there were all in all 4 separate pages, simple 8.5 by 11. I managed to add them all togeh=ther and then discard the triple pages 1. That gave me the correct 4 pages, all diffeent. All done in preview as specified with drag and add, delete extraneous etc.

Comment: Had lunch and the page 3 was identical to p.2, same with p.4 that had printed right before eating. In Acrobat Reader 10, the third and fourth page were always just duplicates of p. 2. And so it was again after lunch. Weird. How can a saved pdf file suddenly display different material? Before and after lunch?